# Passport login with 2 user types

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I currently have a login up and running using Passport in my Node and Express project. Right now I have a users collection that gets the username and password and logs in fine. However, I have 2 separate user types (nurse and doctor) all which have similar fields with the exception of about 4 fields that are different. I'm not sure how to approach implementing 2 different users with the login. Is it best to just have all under users collection with different fields or should I have a separate collection for both users? and if so how would I implement this?

I'm not sure what code to post that can help other than my login code for passport

```
 var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
            User.findOne({ 'username' :  username },
                function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                    if (!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));
                    }
                    // User exists but wrong password, log the error
                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                    }
                    // User and password both match, return user from done method
                    // which will be treated like success
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            );

        })
    );


    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }

}
```

Comment: what doesn't work? if you are using a nosql db, just use one collection for all of them.

Comment: You need roles. check this out. https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-roles

Comment: Then you can have a extra Info column for each user. 
eg. extraInfo : { 'docQualify' : 'MD', 'docMedSchool' : 'Med School' }

extraInfo : { 'nurseQualify' : 'Nursing Course', 'nurseSpeciality' : 'tertiary care' }